# How do I get all of the tracks released in a specific year using Spotify's API?

Tags: api, spotify, spotipy

I am attempting to get all of the tracks release on Spotify for a given year (e.g. all tracks release in 2018)?  I've been looking through their APIs and various projects posted by others, but have not been able to find a solution for this one. One particular issue is the limit on 50 API calls, so as part of a solution, I am looking for a way that I could get the thousands of songs released in a year all at once.

I have tried looking at Spotify API documentation, Spotipy library documentation, and various projects related to this topic, but have not seen anyone tackle this particular issue.